# recursive function for nested object returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through a nested object of objects, looking for a specific object and if I'm I find it, I do stuff. I can get it working for the first nest, but any nest after that I get an undefined value.

```js
let myObj = [{
    id: 1,
    children: [{
        id: 1.1,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 1.2,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [{
        id: 2.1,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 2.2,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
]


function addToObj(itemToAdd, parentId, obj) {

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

    const item = search(obj[i], parentId);

    console.log(item); // undefined

    if (item) {
      item.children = item.children.concat(itemToAdd);
      break;
    }
  }

  function search(obj, id) {
    if (obj.id === id) {
      console.log(obj); // defined (obj with id of 2.1), but returns undefined?
      return obj;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
      search(obj.children[i], id);
    }
  }

  return obj;
};

const itemToAdd = {
  id: 100,
}

addToObj(itemToAdd, 2.1, myObj);
```

The function in the above snippet loops through the object, looking for a specific item. If it finds the item it will insert an object into that items children property.

Comment: when `if (obj.id === id)` is false, there is no return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the return value from the recursive `search`: if it exists, return it:

```
for (let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
  const possibleResult = search(obj.children[i], id);
  if (possibleResult) {
    return possibleResult;
  }
}
```

```js
let myObj = [{
    id: 1,
    children: [{
        id: 1.1,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 1.2,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [{
        id: 2.1,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 2.2,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
]


function addToObj(itemsToAdd, parentId, obj) {

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

    const item = search(obj[i], parentId);

    // first log here will be undefined, nothing found
    // second log here will find the object
    console.log('item', item);

    if (item) {
      item.children = item.children.concat(itemsToAdd);
      break;
    }
  }

  function search(obj, id) {
    if (obj.id === id) {
      console.log('obj', obj); // defined (obj with id of 2.1), but returns undefined?
      return obj;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
      const possibleResult = search(obj.children[i], id);
      if (possibleResult) {
        return possibleResult;
      }
    }
  }

  return obj;
};

const itemToAdd = {
  id: 100,
}

addToObj(itemToAdd, 2.1, myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in code

- if `(obj.id === id)` is `false` then in loop you are returning nothing.
- You should check if `obj.children` exists before loop.

```js
let myObj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [
     {
       id: 1.1,
        children: []
      },
      {
       id: 1.2,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        id: 2.1,
        children: []
      },
      {
       id: 2.2,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
]

There are two problems in code:

 - List item

function addToObj(itemToAdd, parentId, obj) {

  for (let i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {

    const item = search(obj[i], parentId);

    console.log(item); // undefined

    if (item) {
      item.children = item.children.concat(itemToAdd);
      break;
    }
  }

  function search(obj, id) {
    if (obj.id === id) {
      console.log(obj); // defined (obj with id of 2.1), but returns undefined?
      return obj;
    }
    if(obj.children){
    
    for (let i=0;i<obj.children.length;i++) {
       let x = search(obj.children[i], id);
       if(x) return x;
      }
    }
  }

  return obj;
};

const itemToAdd = {
 id: 100,
}

addToObj(itemToAdd, 2.1, myObj);
```